# Is there a well-regarded standard for naming mundane user profile fields?

Tags: standards, profile, naming

Many years ago, I worked on a project where we needed to design a schema for recording fairly mundane user profile fields, such as the user’s name, address, and phone number.  At the time, my team found ourselves debating over property names like `lastName` vs. `surname`, `workPhone` vs. `officePhone`, `zipCode` vs. `postalCode`, etc.  Then we discovered that there had already been some effort to settle these questions, and it had been documented by a standards group – maybe ISO? – that expressed unambiguous opinions on such field names.

Years later – new employer, new project, same problem – but now I am unable to recall or locate that standard.

Please understand, in this question, that I am *not* soliciting anyone’s personal opinion about what all the field names should be.  I am merely asking if anyone can help me locate some standards documentation on this topic that has been published by a well-regarded standards organization, or any other similarly authoritative and respected reference.

One other note, though it's probably irrelevant.  In this project, there is no desire to be world-compatible.  Being United States-centric is completely acceptable, even if it is perhaps short-sighted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org has a wide range of schemas "for structured data on the Internet".

Your particular needs may be met by the `Person` schema: https://schema.org/Person

Microsoft also has a Common Data Model with an even more structured set of schemas: https://github.com/microsoft/CDM/tree/master/schemaDocuments/core/applicationCommon. In your case perhaps the `User` model could be useful: https://github.com/microsoft/CDM/blob/master/schemaDocuments/core/applicationCommon/User.cdm.json

Comment: The schema.org reference is exactly what I have been looking for, and I imagine it will also be useful for others that Google brings here.  Thanks!